# Convert many to many relation to tables in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, many-to-many, data-modeling, conceptual

I have the following tables in my model:

```
Store table:            domain(key), name
Product table:          url(key), name
Products_Stores table:  store_domain(key), product_url(key), url, score
```

I've took some courses from [DataStax](https://www.datastax.com/) but still have no idea how to convert this conceptual model to logical. I mean do I need to have 3 tables like relational databases? If so, how?

Please be completely clear, because I have more such relations between my entities.

Comment: First place to start with is to write down the queries that will be served from these three potential tables to be converted. Provide your queries to further continue with modeling on Cassandra

Answer (score 0):

If the version of your cassandra is 2.0+, you can use the following approach.

Besides tables to store information about stores and products, which are your first two ones ("Store table" and "Product table"), to represent many to many relation you need two additional tables (4 in total):

- Products by stores table: `store_domain(partition key), product_url(clustering column)`
- Stores by products table: `product_url(partition key), store_domain(clustering column)`

So, to retrieve all products for a store, you need to request the 1st table specifying store_domain. To retrieve all stores for a product, request the 2nd table specifying product_url.

For both tables the combound key consists of `store_domain` and `product_url`, which makes records unique for each `store_domain + product_url` pair.

As you add a new relation between a product and a store, you need to save it in both tables. Consider saving it using [Batch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html) to make it atomic.